# Is it possible to run (py)LIon Lammps package on ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, windows, rar

I am curretnly trying to install (py)LIon (A package for simulating trapped ion trajectories) on my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS using only [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1neh0tz7ghwcqwx/AAA8HANy4YdE6H91LTQzLSpda/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%20LION.docx?dl=0) instruction for windows. I have not any possibility now to find instructions for ubuntu and there is no information about this package in internet at all. I build the Lammps package and changed path to lmp_serial in Lion.rar archive, but still don't understand what to do.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: @AslanMonahov Also need to get some clarification on the tag [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux].  Are you using Ubuntu under WSL on Windows?  You don't mention it in the question (or title) itself, which makes me think you may have selected that tag erroneously.  If you *are* using WSL, please update the question to reflect it, but otherwise please remove that tag.  Thanks!

Comment: Please apply all system security upgrades & fixes; a fully upgraded 20.04 system will report as 20.04.5 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded to 20.04.5 in the week+ before that ISO release date).  Being behind on security fixes may complicate your issue.